# Twiliorestful API service for outgoing SMS, with restrictive firewall

Tags: url, twilio, firewall, ports

We are using the C# Twiliorestful Client for outgoing SMS messages using a C# application. What port/web address to configure for firewall access?  Our network only allows specific url/ports to be accessed from the servers.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The Twilio API is available at https://*.twilio.com. There are a few subdomains in use right now, but if you only need SMS messages then the base URL https://api.twilio.com should do you. This is over port 443 as all Twilio API calls are made over SSL.

Let me know if that helps!

Comment: Thank you that seems so simple but is exactly the answer i couldn't find on their website or even requesting information from them directly..

Comment: No problem! Would you mind accepting the answer so that anyone else who comes across this can see? Thanks!

Comment: We have the same situation as OP, but our firewall requires IP Ranges/CIDR blocks for egress. Are they deterministic for api.twilio.com?

Comment: Hey Chris, would you mind dropping me an email at philnash@twilio.com with your full requirements? Cheers.